# no reverse match only in server version

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error when in my django app. But this only happens when I passed the files to the server. In localhost it's working fine.

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'logoutUser' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

in this line:

```
 <a href=" {% url "logoutUser" %} " class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sair</a>
```

This is the traceback:

```
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  447.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  433.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  532.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  452.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'logoutUser' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    ...

    #  cart 
    url(r'^carrinho$', 'simulado.views.carrinho'),
    url(r'^buyItem$', 'simulado.views.buyItem', name = "buyItem"),

    # logout
    url(r'^logoutUser$', 'simulado.views.logoutUser', name = "logoutUser"),

    #  obrigado, return from pagseguro 
    url(r'^obrigado$', 'simulado.views.obrigado'),

    ...


)
```

Comment: how does your `urls.py` look like?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko i updated it

Comment: nothing suspicious. What about your settings and the project strucute?

Comment: What part of settings do you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need trailing slashes in your urls, or you need to set the APPEND_SLASH setting in your settings.
More information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#append-slash